# Chromium; how to get rid of the black circular X button in fullscreen mode?

Tags: chromium

In Chromium version 72.0.3626.121 the button to leave the fullscreen mode could be disabled by using the enable-experimental-fullscreen-exit-ui flag. In version 86.0.4240.193, this flag is no longer available.

Does somebody know how to disable this button?

I'm using the following options to start Chromium.
"chrome.exe" --no-default-browser-check --DisableSplashScreen=true --disable-infobars --overscroll-history-navigation=0 --js-flags="--expose-gc" --incognito --start-fullscreen

Adding the --kiosk option disables the button, but it also changes the behavior of the browser, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Appologisied if I'm wrong, and I do not propose this as a proper answer to your question, but this is what I think.

It might be possible that the only way to achieve what you want is to rebuild the browser from the source. For example, I wanted my bookmark UI to show a list bigger than few last items, was thinking this could be tweaked by a plugin or config, but it turns out it's a hardcoded const variable in the source code. An extension could use a different bookmarker to replace the bundled one. However, nothing can change that const value except changing it in the code and recompiling the browser.

Without knowing much internals it feels to me the X is there on purpose as safety, not to allow somebody to take advantage of less tech-savvy users (imagine a Windows login screen made in HTML to steal users credentials). Therefore I think very likely you will not be able to do what you want easily. A lot of the experiments and features get removed from the browser, remember the vertical-tabs were there for few versions as a hidden command-line argument, but then that got removed too.